# ASP.net MVC Downloading Excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have managed to create the Excel file using HTMLTextwriter, but the returned file is into a Javascript function.

The view code is:

```
<input type="submit" id = "exportExcelBtn" class = "searchButton" value="Export To Excel" 
onclick= "ExportToExcel();"/>
```

The JS function then gets the data required for the control action, and then calls the relevant action, as such:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Search/ExportToExcel",
    data: { //parameters        },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error.responseText);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

The Excel file is created, by deriving from ActionResult, and returned back to the JS method. The created Excel file is written to the browser as such:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Clear();

            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
            context.Response.Charset = "";

            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
            context.Response.Write(content);
            context.Response.End();
```

How then can I get that file downloaded to the users computer?

I can easily just use File.WriteAllText in the model method, but I feel that is cheating the MVC method?

Comment: You should redirect to the resource with a link. Why dont link to the Action ?

Comment: @dknaack, do you mean link direct from the view to the action?

Comment: yes, why not. If the content-type your ActionResult responding is excel the user will stay on the current page and will get the download dialog.

Comment: The data that I need to pass into the ActionResult method are within the .js file, so I need to get access to that data, hence why I have used Ajax.  I am new to web dev, only a week, so I know that i'm probably going about it the wrong way at the moment.  Any idea's how I can get that data from the.js file, into the view page?

Comment: which "data" ist in the js file ? Can you send them as parameters to the download action ?

Comment: @dknaack, they are just strings of selected items.  How can I get their values from the HTML view?  I usually can only get them from within a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `File.WriteAllText` in the model.
That will write it to the server.

You need to set the `location` to a URL that returns the contents of the Excel file.
The correct way to do that in MVC is to `return File(content,"application/x-ms-excel", fileName)`

Comment: @ Slaks, thanks. The location of what? Sorry, i've only been doing web dev for around a week :)

Comment: The Javascript `location` property, which sets the location of the current browser tab.

Answer (score 3):

You are sending the Excel file itself as a response to an AJAX request. This will require JavaScript to recognize and parse the file, and, more importantly, to save it to disk. This is inappropriate (and, probably, impossible).

I recommend you to get rid of AJAX, and open the link `/Search/ExportToExcel` in another browser window. Then the browser (not your JS, but the browser) will be receiving the file and saving it.