# Download Excel file via AJAX MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, export-to-excel

I have a large(ish) form in MVC.

I need to be able to generate an excel file containing data from a subset of that form.

The tricky bit is that this shouldn't affect the rest of the form and so I want to do it via AJAX. I've come across a few questions on SO that seem to be related, but I can't quite work out what the answers mean.

This one seems the closest to what I'm after: [asp-net-mvc-downloading-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747532/asp-net-mvc-downloading-excel) - but I'm not sure I understand the response, and it is a couple years old now. I also came across another article (can't find it anymore) about using an iframe to handle the file download, but I'm not sure how to get this working with MVC.

My excel file returns fine if I'm doing a full post back but I can't get it working with AJAX in mvc.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

You can't directly return a file for download via an AJAX call so, an alternative approach is to to use an AJAX call to post the related data to your server. You can then use server side code to create the Excel File (I would recommend using EPPlus or NPOI for this although it sounds as if you have this part working).

> **UPDATE September 2016**

My original answer (below) was over 3 years old, so I thought I would update as I no longer create files on the server when downloading files via AJAX however, I have left the original answer as it may be of some use still depending on your specific requirements.

A common scenario in my MVC applications is reporting via a web page that has some user configured report parameters (Date Ranges, Filters etc.). When the user has specified the parameters they post them to the server, the report is generated (say for example an Excel file as output) and then I store the resulting file as a byte array in the `TempData` bucket with a unique reference. This reference is passed back as a Json Result to my AJAX function that subsequently redirects to separate controller action to extract the data from `TempData` and download to the end users browser.

To give this more detail, assuming you have a MVC View that has a form bound to a Model class, lets call the Model `ReportVM`.

First, a controller action is required to receive the posted model, an example would be:

```
public ActionResult PostReportPartial(ReportVM model){

   // Validate the Model is correct and contains valid data
   // Generate your report output based on the model parameters
   // This can be an Excel, PDF, Word file - whatever you need.

   // As an example lets assume we've generated an EPPlus ExcelPackage

   ExcelPackage workbook = new ExcelPackage();
   // Do something to populate your workbook

   // Generate a new unique identifier against which the file can be stored
   string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

   using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()){
        workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        TempData[handle] = memoryStream.ToArray();
   }      

   // Note we are returning a filename as well as the handle
   return new JsonResult() { 
         Data = new { FileGuid = handle, FileName = "TestReportOutput.xlsx" }
   };

}
```

The AJAX call that posts my MVC form to the above controller and receives the response looks like this:

```
$ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: '/Report/PostReportPartial',
    data: _form.serialize(), 
    success: function (data){
         var response = JSON.parse(data);
         window.location = '/Report/Download?fileGuid=' + response.FileGuid 
                           + '&filename=' + response.FileName;
    }
})
```

The controller action to handle the downloading of the file:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Download(string fileGuid, string fileName)
{   
   if(TempData[fileGuid] != null){
        byte[] data = TempData[fileGuid] as byte[];
        return File(data, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);
   }   
   else{
        // Problem - Log the error, generate a blank file,
        //           redirect to another controller action - whatever fits with your application
        return new EmptyResult();
   }
}
```

One other change that could easily be accommodated if required is to pass the MIME Type of the file as a third parameter so that the one Controller action could correctly serve a variety of output file formats.

This removes any need for any physical files to created and stored on the server, so no housekeeping routines required and once again this is seamless to the end user.

Note, the advantage of using `TempData` rather than `Session` is that once `TempData` is read the data is cleared so it will be more efficient in terms of memory usage if you have a high volume of file requests. See [TempData Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422930/using-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-best-practice).

> **ORIGINAL Answer**

You can't directly return a file for download via an AJAX call so, an alternative approach is to to use an AJAX call to post the related data to your server. You can then use server side code to create the Excel File (I would recommend using EPPlus or NPOI for this although it sounds as if you have this part working).

Once the file has been created on the server pass back the path to the file (or just the filename) as the return value to your AJAX call and then set the JavaScript `window.location` to this URL which will prompt the browser to download the file.

From the end users perspective, the file download operation is seamless as they never leave the page on which the request originates.

Below is a simple contrived example of an ajax call to achieve this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Reports/ExportMyData', 
    data: '{ "dataprop1": "test", "dataprop2" : "test2" }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (returnValue) {
        window.location = '/Reports/Download?file=' + returnValue;
    }
});
```

- **url** parameter is the Controller/Action method where your code will create the Excel file.
- **data** parameter contains the json data that would be extracted from the form.
- **returnValue** would be the file name of your newly created Excel file.
- The **window.location** command redirects to the Controller/Action method that actually returns your file for download.

A sample controller method for the Download action would be:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Download(string file)
{   
  string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles"), file);
  return File(fullPath, "application/vnd.ms-excel", file);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good potential option, but before I go ahead with it, are there no other alternatives that don't involve creating the file on the server first?

Comment: Not that I am aware of - this approach I have used successfully many times. From the users perspective it is seamless, the only thing to be mindful of is that you will need a housekeeping routine to tidy up the files that are created as they will mount up over time.

Comment: http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: We plan to put the data into a stream, cache it in memory, then retrieve it.  This should keep the files off the server.

Comment: Creating an endpoint '/Download?file=...' SCREAMS massive security risk - I'm no security expert but I'd think you'd want to add user authentication, input sanitation, MVC's [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and mention other security best-practices to this answer.

Comment: I don't suppose you know the names space for File in this line: return File(data, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);  I don't have a File that accepts these arguments.

Comment: @JakeGaston it is in `System.Web.Mvc` and returns a `FileContentResult`

Comment: What if this is a single page App? How do we trigger it when the hash changes?

Comment: @CSL I'm always getting the error 0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character on the var response = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: this works for small strings sent to the server side, otherwise you will get a HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long. Increasing exponentially the limit for query string opens a security risk and also not necessarily match all file sizes.

Comment: Great, why don't you put the old answer at the bottom? And the new answer at the top, so people don't waste time

Comment: This worked for me with a relative/virtual path. Something like: `/Images/SampleImage.jpg` but it didn't work with an absolute/physical/full path (`http://www.google.com/Images/SampleImage.jpg`).

Comment: @goamn Good idea I have switched the answers around - thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It doesn't trigger the Download method from JavaScript.

Comment: I get a 502 bad gateway at the end even though everything seems fine when debugging. I've narrowed it down to know that the 502 doesn't happen if I don't try to set the tempdata to a byte array. But how else can I persist the byte array data?

Comment: I had to use IMemoryCache instead of TempData. I'll post an answer below for anyone who it may help.

Comment: Kudos, @CSL. The updated solution is GREAT! Just one thing - I don't believe that you need the JSON.parse() after the first AJAX return, since the data is already JSON formatted on the server with the return. Thanks again!

Comment: I had to update the approach, as @HumbleBeginnings says the JSON.parse(data) is not required as its already a JavaScript object so you can just access the object with data.FileGuid.  I also had to add  JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet on the JsonResult in the controller

Comment: TempData have a max size limit, it will not works if the file size is large.

Answer (score 19):

My 2 cents - you don't need to store the excel as a physical file on the server - instead, store it in the (Session) Cache. Use a uniquely generated name for your Cache variable (that stores that excel file) - this will be the return of your (initial) ajax call. This way you don't have to deal with file access issues, managing (deleting) the files when not needed, etc. and, having the file in the Cache, is faster to retrieve it.

Comment: How exactly would you do that? Sounds interesting.

Comment: An example would be nice (i mean how to store it in the cache, not generating the excel file).

Comment: How scalable is this though? If a user is downloading several large reports?

Comment: If you are on Azure, session will works UNTIL you turn OFF ARRAffinity.

Answer (score 18):

I was recently able to accomplish this in MVC (although there was no need to use AJAX) without creating a physical file and thought I'd share my code:

Super simple JavaScript function (datatables.net button click triggers this):

```
function getWinnersExcel(drawingId) {
    window.location = "/drawing/drawingwinnersexcel?drawingid=" + drawingId;
}
```

C# Controller code:

```
    public FileResult DrawingWinnersExcel(int drawingId)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(); // cleaned up automatically by MVC
        List<DrawingWinner> winnerList = DrawingDataAccess.GetWinners(drawingId); // simple entity framework-based data retrieval
        ExportHelper.GetWinnersAsExcelMemoryStream(stream, winnerList, drawingId);

        string suggestedFilename = string.Format("Drawing_{0}_Winners.xlsx", drawingId);
        return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml", suggestedFilename);
    }
```

In the ExportHelper class I do use a 3rd party tool ([GemBox.Spreadsheet](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview)) to generate the Excel file and it has a Save to Stream option.  That being said, there are a number of ways to create Excel files that can easily be written to a memory stream.

```
public static class ExportHelper
{
    internal static void GetWinnersAsExcelMemoryStream(MemoryStream stream, List<DrawingWinner> winnerList, int drawingId)
    {

        ExcelFile ef = new ExcelFile();

        // lots of excel worksheet building/formatting code here ...

        ef.SaveXlsx(stream);
        stream.Position = 0; // reset for future read

     }
}
```

In IE, Chrome, and Firefox, the browser prompts to download the file and no actual navigation occurs.

Comment: I had a similar approach. The problem is you don't know when the download is over so you can stop that damn preloader :)

Answer (score 8):

First Create the controller action that will create the Excel File

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ExportExcel()
{
    DataTable dt = DataService.GetData();
    var fileName = "Excel_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".xls";

    //save the file to server temp folder
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/temp"), fileName);

    using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //I don't show the detail how to create the Excel, this is not the point of this article,
        //I just use the NPOI for Excel handler
        Utility.WriteDataTableToExcel(dt, ".xls", exportData);

        FileStream file = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        exportData.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
    }

    var errorMessage = "you can return the errors in here!";

    //return the Excel file name
    return Json(new { fileName = fileName, errorMessage = "" });
}
```

then create the Download action

```
[HttpGet]
[DeleteFileAttribute] //Action Filter, it will auto delete the file after download, 
                      //I will explain it later
public ActionResult Download(string file)
{
    //get the temp folder and file path in server
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/temp"), file);

    //return the file for download, this is an Excel 
    //so I set the file content type to "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    return File(fullPath, "application/vnd.ms-excel", file);
}
```

if you want to delete the file after downloaded create this

```
public class DeleteFileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();

        //convert the current filter context to file and get the file path
        string filePath = (filterContext.Result as FilePathResult).FileName;

        //delete the file after download
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

and finally ajax call from you MVC Razor view

```
//I use blockUI for loading...
$.blockUI({ message: '<h3>Please wait a moment...</h3>' });    
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ExportExcel","YourController")', //call your controller and action
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
}).done(function (data) {
    //console.log(data.result);
    $.unblockUI();

    //get the file name for download
    if (data.fileName != "") {
        //use window.location.href for redirect to download action for download the file
        window.location.href = "@Url.RouteUrl(new 
            { Controller = "YourController", Action = "Download"})/?file=" + data.fileName;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I used the solution posted by CSL but I would recommend you dont store the file data in Session during the whole session. By using TempData the file data is automatically removed after the next request (which is the GET request for the file). You could also manage removal of the file data in Session in download action.

Session could consume much memory/space depending on SessionState storage and how many files are exported during the session and if you have many users.

I've updated the serer side code from CSL to use TempData instead.

```
public ActionResult PostReportPartial(ReportVM model){

   // Validate the Model is correct and contains valid data
   // Generate your report output based on the model parameters
   // This can be an Excel, PDF, Word file - whatever you need.

   // As an example lets assume we've generated an EPPlus ExcelPackage

   ExcelPackage workbook = new ExcelPackage();
   // Do something to populate your workbook

   // Generate a new unique identifier against which the file can be stored
   string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

   using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()){
        workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        TempData[handle] = memoryStream.ToArray();
   }      

   // Note we are returning a filename as well as the handle
   return new JsonResult() { 
         Data = new { FileGuid = handle, FileName = "TestReportOutput.xlsx" }
   };

}

[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Download(string fileGuid, string fileName)
{   
   if(TempData[fileGuid] != null){
        byte[] data = TempData[fileGuid] as byte[];
        return File(data, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);
   }   
   else{
        // Problem - Log the error, generate a blank file,
        //           redirect to another controller action - whatever fits with your application
        return new EmptyResult();
   }
}
```

Comment: @Nichlas I had started using TempData also, your answer prompted me to update mine to reflect this!

Answer (score 5):

using ClosedXML.Excel;

```
   public ActionResult Downloadexcel()
    {   
        var Emplist = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbcontext.Employees.ToList());
        DataTable dt11 = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Emplist, (typeof(DataTable)));
        dt11.TableName = "Emptbl";
        FileContentResult robj;
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt11);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(stream);
                var bytesdata = File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "myFileName.xlsx");
                robj = bytesdata;
            }
        }


        return Json(robj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: In AJAX CALL Success Block,
success: function (Rdata) {
                    debugger;
                    var bytes = new Uint8Array(Rdata.FileContents); 
                    var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    link.download = "myFileName.xlsx";
                    link.click();
                },

Comment: some one Have implemented Excel file download in the above link, it works only for @html.Beginform() then after small changes need that code, for AJAX call Success Block, Please Check it, it works fine in AJAX CALL

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/Downloadexcel/",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: null,
                success: function (Rdata) {
                    debugger;
                    var bytes = new Uint8Array(Rdata.FileContents); 
                    var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    link.download = "myFileName.xlsx";
                    link.click();
                },
                error: function (err) {

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  $.ajax({
    global: false,
    url: SitePath + "/User/ExportTeamMembersInExcel",
    "data": { 'UserName': UserName, 'RoleId': RoleId, UserIds: AppraseeId },
    "type": "POST",
    "dataType": "JSON",
   "success": function (result) {
        
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(result.FileContents);
        var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "myFileName.xlsx";
        link.click();
      },
    "error": function () {
        alert("error");
    }
})


[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ExportTeamMembersInExcel(string UserName, long? RoleId, string[] UserIds)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        FileContentResult robj;
        DataTable data = objuserservice.ExportTeamToExcel(UserName, RoleId, UserIds);
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(data, "TeamMembers");
            using (stream)
            {
                wb.SaveAs(stream);
            }
        }
        robj = File(stream.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "TeamMembers.xlsx");
        return Json(robj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: cannot open the file, the excel just open and doesn't then just close itself, I even added stream.close() just before robj but not working.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't quite work for me as I got a **502 Bad Gateway** result from the ajax call even though everything seemed to be returning fine from the controller.

Perhaps I was hitting a limit with TempData - not sure, but I found that if I used **IMemoryCache** instead of **TempData**, it worked fine, so here is my adapted version of the code in the accepted answer:

```
public ActionResult PostReportPartial(ReportVM model){

   // Validate the Model is correct and contains valid data
   // Generate your report output based on the model parameters
   // This can be an Excel, PDF, Word file - whatever you need.

   // As an example lets assume we've generated an EPPlus ExcelPackage

   ExcelPackage workbook = new ExcelPackage();
   // Do something to populate your workbook

   // Generate a new unique identifier against which the file can be stored
   string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

   using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()){
        workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        //TempData[handle] = memoryStream.ToArray();

        //This is an equivalent to tempdata, but requires manual cleanup
        _cache.Set(handle, memoryStream.ToArray(), 
                    new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))); 
                    //(I'd recommend you revise the expiration specifics to suit your application)

   }      

   // Note we are returning a filename as well as the handle
   return new JsonResult() { 
         Data = new { FileGuid = handle, FileName = "TestReportOutput.xlsx" }
   };

}
```

AJAX call remains as with the accepted answer (I made no changes):

```
$ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: '/Report/PostReportPartial',
    data: _form.serialize(), 
    success: function (data){
         var response = JSON.parse(data);
         window.location = '/Report/Download?fileGuid=' + response.FileGuid 
                           + '&filename=' + response.FileName;
    }
})
```

The controller action to handle the downloading of the file:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Download(string fileGuid, string fileName)
{   
    if (_cache.Get<byte[]>(fileGuid) != null)
    {
        byte[] data = _cache.Get<byte[]>(fileGuid);
        _cache.Remove(fileGuid); //cleanup here as we don't need it in cache anymore
        return File(data, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        // Something has gone wrong...
        return View("Error"); // or whatever/wherever you want to return the user
    }
}
```

...

Now there is some extra code for setting up MemoryCache...

In order to use "_cache" I injected in the constructor for the controller like so:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
namespace MySolution.Project.Controllers
{
 public class MyController : Controller
 {
     private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

     public LogController(IMemoryCache cache)
     {
        _cache = cache;
     }

     //rest of controller code here
  }
 }
```

And make sure you have the following in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

Answer (score 1):

I may sound quite naive, and *may* attract quite a criticism, but here's how I did it,
(*It doesn't involve **`ajax`** for export, but it **doesn't do** a full postback  either* )

*Thanks for [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52679645/1042705) answer.*
**Create a simple controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{               
   /* A demo action
    public ActionResult Index()
    {           
        return View(model);
    }
   */
    [HttpPost]
    public FileResult ExportData()
    {
        /* An example filter
        var filter = TempData["filterKeys"] as MyFilter;
        TempData.Keep();            */
        var someList = db.GetDataFromDb(/*filter*/) // filter as an example

    /*May be here's the trick, I'm setting my filter in TempData["filterKeys"] 
     in an action,(GetFilteredPartial() illustrated below) when 'searching' for the data,
     so do not really need ajax here..to pass my filters.. */

     //Some utility to convert list to Datatable
     var dt = Utility.ConvertToDataTable(someList); 

      //  I am using EPPlus nuget package 
      using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
      {
          ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
          ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {                   
              pck.SaveAs(memoryStream);
              return File(memoryStream.ToArray(),
              "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
              "ExportFileName.xlsx");                    
            }                
        }   
    }

    //This is just a supporting example to illustrate setting up filters ..        
   /* [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult GetFilteredPartial(MyFilter filter)
    {            
        TempData["filterKeys"] = filter;
        var filteredData = db.GetConcernedData(filter);
        var model = new MainViewModel();
        model.PartialViewModel = filteredData;

        return PartialView("_SomePartialView", model);
    } */     
}
```

And here are the *Views..*

```
/*Commenting out the View code, in order to focus on the imp. code     
 @model Models.MainViewModel
 @{Layout...}     

      Some code for, say, a partial View  
      <div id="tblSampleBody">
        @Html.Partial("_SomePartialView", Model.PartialViewModel)
      </div>
  */                                                       
//The actual part.. Just **posting** this bit of data from the complete View...
//Here, you are not posting the full Form..or the complete View
   @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Export Data" />
    }
//...
//</div>

/*And you may require to pass search/filter values.. as said in the accepted answer..
That can be done while 'searching' the data.. and not while
 we need an export..for instance:-             

<script>             
  var filterData = {
      SkipCount: someValue,
      TakeCount: 20,
      UserName: $("#UserName").val(),
      DepartmentId: $("#DepartmentId").val(),     
   }

  function GetFilteredData() {
       $("#loader").show();
       filterData.SkipCount = 0;
       $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("GetFilteredPartial","Home")',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: "html",
          data: filterData,
          success: function (dataHTML) {
          if ((dataHTML === null) || (dataHTML == "")) {
              $("#tblSampleBody").html('<tr><td>No Data Returned</td></tr>');
                $("#loader").hide();
            } else {
                $("#tblSampleBody").html(dataHTML);                    
                $("#loader").hide();
            }
        }
     });
   }    
</script>*/
```

The whole point of the *trick* seems that, we are posting a form (a *part* of the Razor View ) upon which we are  *calling* an `Action method`, which returns: a **`FileResult`**, and this ***`FileResult`*** returns  ***`the Excel File`***.. 
*And for posting the filter values, as said, ( and if you require to), I am making a post request to another action, as has been attempted to describe..*

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Make sure you return a File from your controller action with contentType as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" and file name as e.g. "List.xlsx" which should be the same as in the AJAX success call. I have used ClosedXML NuGet package to generate the excel file.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Export",
    type: 'GET',      
    contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' },
    success: function (data) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'List.xlsx';
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me create my own solution that I will share here. I was using a GET ajax request at first without issues but it got to a point where the request URL length was exceeded so I had to swith to a POST.

The javascript uses JQuery file download plugin and consists of 2 succeeding calls. One POST (To send params) and one GET to retreive the file.

```
 function download(result) {
        $.fileDownload(uri + "?guid=" + result,
        {
            successCallback: onSuccess.bind(this),
            failCallback: onFail.bind(this)
        });
    }

    var uri = BASE_EXPORT_METADATA_URL;
    var data = createExportationData.call(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: download.bind(this),
        fail: onFail.bind(this)
    });
```

Server side

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string MassExportDocuments(MassExportDocumentsInput input)
    {
        // Save query for file download use
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(guid.ToString(), input, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        return guid.ToString();
    }

   [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MassExportDocuments([FromUri] Guid guid)
    {
        //Get params from cache, generate and return
        var model = (MassExportDocumentsInput)HttpContext.Current.Cache[guid.ToString()];
          ..... // Document generation

        // to determine when file is downloaded
        HttpContext.Current
                   .Response
                   .SetCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true") { Path = "/" });

        return FileResult(memoryStream, "documents.zip", "application/zip");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSL's answer was implemented in a project I'm working on but the problem I incurred was scaling out on Azure broke our file downloads. Instead, I was able to do this with one AJAX call:

**SERVER**

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult DownloadInvoice(int id1, int id2)
{
    //necessary to get the filename in the success of the ajax callback
    HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");

    byte[] fileBytes = _service.GetInvoice(id1, id2);
    string fileName = "Invoice.xlsx";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

**CLIENT**
(modified version of [Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post/23797348#23797348))

```
$("#downloadInvoice").on("click", function() {
    $("#loaderInvoice").removeClass("d-none");

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = [];
    xhr.open('POST', "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("DownloadInvoice", "Controller", new { id1 = Model.Id1, id2 = Model.Id2 }))", true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var filename = "";
            var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }
            var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

            var blob = typeof File === 'function'
                ? new File([this.response], filename, { type: type })
                : new Blob([this.response], { type: type });
            if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                if (filename) {
                    // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    // safari doesn't support this yet
                    if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                        window.location = downloadUrl;
                    } else {
                        a.href = downloadUrl;
                        a.download = filename;
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                    }
                } else {
                    window.location = downloadUrl;

                }

                setTimeout(function() {
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
                    $("#loaderInvoice").addClass("d-none");
                }, 100); // cleanup
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send($.param(params));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Asp.Net WebForm and just I wanna to download a file from server side. There is a lot article but I cannot find just basic answer.
Now, I tried a basic way and got it.

That's my problem.

I have to create a lot of input button dynamically on runtime. And I want to add each button to download button with giving an unique fileNumber.

I create each button like this:

```js
fragment += "<div><input type=\"button\" value=\"Create Excel\" onclick=\"CreateExcelFile(" + fileNumber + ");\" /></div>";
```

Each button call this ajax method.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.aspx/CreateExcelFile',
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (returnValue) {
      window.location = '/Reports/Downloads/' + returnValue.d;
    }
});
```

Then I wrote a basic simple method.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string CreateExcelFile2(string fileNumber)
{
    string filePath = string.Format(@"Form_{0}.xlsx", fileNumber);
    return filePath;
}
```

I am generating this Form_1, Form_2, Form_3.... And I am going to delete this old files with another program. But if there is a way to just sending byte array to download file like using Response. I wanna to use it.

I hope this will be usefull for anyone.

Answer (score -1):

On Submit form

```
public ActionResult ExportXls()
{   
 var filePath="";
  CommonHelper.WriteXls(filePath, "Text.xls");
}

 public static void WriteXls(string filePath, string targetFileName)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.Charset = "utf-8";
            response.ContentType = "text/xls";
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", targetFileName));
            response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
            response.End();
        }
    }
```