# Download a file via web service and jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, download

I'm trying to create in **asp.net 2.0** a web service to download a file (pop up window with Open or Save the file), in this way:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "webservice.asmx/download",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (res) {
            console.log("donwloaded");
        }
    });
```

And in "webservice.asmx"

```
[WebMethod()]
public byte[] DownloadFile(string FName)
{
    System.IO.FileStream fs1 = null;
    fs1 = System.IO.File.Open(FName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] b1 = new byte[fs1.Length];
    fs1.Read(b1, 0, (int)fs1.Length);
    fs1.Close();
    return b1;
}

[WebMethod]
public void download()
{
    string filename = "test.txt";
    string path = "C:\\test.txt";

    byte[] ls1 = DownloadFile(path);
    HttpResponse response = Context.Response;

    response.Clear();
    response.BufferOutput = true;
    response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

    response.BinaryWrite(ls1);

    response.Flush();
    response.Close();
}
```

In this way I see the contents of the file (I can't to download the file whith a popup window).

Where I wrong? Is it possible to do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: You would have to open a new window and invoke this ajax part in that new window.

Comment: I think the content type is different for a file in order to appear as a downloadable.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Actually the ajax call is in click event on aspx page....(for "popup window" I mean the default confirm window of the browser)

Comment: Oh ok .. I think then popu part is working for you. For the above part , I was telling to open a blank URL with the above JS pasted but you can ignore that. Quite interesting , haven't tried AJAX requests for file downloading , not sure if An AJAX response can come in different contenttype

Comment: I think the answer in to this question might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670209/download-excel-file-via-ajax-mvc

Answer (score 1):

that is not a good way , to make file download thru popup window , just open a new pop and make the url of that window to point to your file or webservice url .

```
window.open("fileurl"  )
```

Answer (score 0):

a good way to do it is simply redirect the browser to the "webservice.asmx/download" instead of calling that via ajax. i.e.

```
window.location.href = 'webservice.asmx/download';
```

when browser will detect you returning octet-stream, it will ask to download the file but will not clear/eraze the page you were on.

Comment: but can i send a json object to server in this way?

Comment: you can serialize json object then urlencode it , but it is wrong approach and not recommended

Comment: no and I didn't notice you want the download to start as a result of a POST... not a great idea I think - no download resume