# How to export data to Excel using ASP.NET MVC 5 without reloading the page?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq

The process of exporting the data into Excel is working. But I don't need to reload the page. When I try to press the Export Data to Excel the page is reloading. How to avoid this? Please, help. Thank you.

C#:

```
public ActionResult Export(int id) {
    Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
    var export = _context.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == id)ToList();

    worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Name";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Age";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Position";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Address";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Contact";

    foreach (var e in export)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, 1] = e.Name;
        worksheet.Cells[row, 2] = e.Age;
        worksheet.Cells[row, 3] = e.Position;
        worksheet.Cells[row, 4] = e.Address;
        worksheet.Cells[row, 5] = e.Contact;

        row++;
    }

    workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Excel\sample.xls");
    workbook.Close();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);

    application.Quit();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(application);

    return View();
}
```

Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".js-export").click(function(e) {
            var link = $(e.target);
             $.ajax({
                    url: "/home/export/" + link.attr("data-export-id"),
                    method: "GET"
                    })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Event:

```
<a href="#" class="js-export btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-export-id="@item.Id">Export to Excel</a>
```

Comment: `return View()` seems odd. Shouldn't you be sending the file back in the response stream?

Comment: Are you sure the link you put is really what calls the Ajax event? There is no class in it with `js-delete-property`, and it does not have a `data-id` attribute, it has `data-export-id`.

Comment: Yes, I use return View(). How is that "result stream"? Can you help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670209/download-excel-file-via-ajax-mvc

Comment: @GhasanAl-Sakkaf please see I updated it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using ActionResult you can use JsonResult and can return only url of excel file :-

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/home/export/" + link.attr("data-export-id"),
            dataType: 'json',                
            success: function (data) {                  
               console.log(data.ExcelUrl);
            }
        });
```

Your code in controller :-

```
 public JsonResult Export(int id)
        {   
          //Exel generation code  here showing in your post. 
          return Json(new { ExcelUrl = "New Excel URL path" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

Comment: Hi Anand, yes good suggestion. What is New Excel URL path? I can't understand.

Comment: Thanks, Its your excel file path like "C:\Excel\sample.xls". Please mark it as answer if it solve your issue, so other can use it.

Comment: //Get excel URL Here , you can get excel url here that you return from JsonResult method. As I get it like "data.ExcelUrl"

Comment: One more thing Anand. Please, can you edit the example above? Thank you. The ajax part.

Comment: You should be sending file stream instead of file path unless the file path is shared one or in cloud blob storage. How will the client be able to access the C:\ drive or whatever drive of the server where you save the file?

Comment: @Developer you are talking about file stream. Can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 0):

Call the action via `$.ajax` and return `FileResult` in the action:

```
public FileResult Export(int id) 
 {
    //.........your file creation logic goes here ....//

    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
 }
```

Comment: @Paul - `filePath` is the path where you have saved the file. In your sample, its `C:\Excel\sample.xls`

Comment: I tried it but why it doesn't have a prompt like download?

Comment: Is it downloading the file now? or just that the prompt is missing?

Comment: downloading the file now, but prompt is missing it must see like google when download in the bottom of the browser right?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome should show the downloaded file at the bottom of the browser unless you have some local setting done in your broswer