# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Don't happens anything when try download file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I build a asp.net mvc 5 project and some point i want to download file, the file can be anything for example: 'pdf', 'doc', 'zip'.

I try the following code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Download")]
    public ActionResult DownloadFiles(string data)// data is the name folder where the file/files exists
    {
            string pathFolder = $@"{db.GetDetails().PathToFolder}\{data}";//PathToFolder is the root folder
            if (Directory.Exists(pathFolder))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pathFolder);
                if (files.Length > 1)
                {
                    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                    {
                        zip.AddDirectory(pathFolder);

                        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                        zip.Save(output);
                        return File(output, "application/zip", "zipfile.zip");
                    }
                }
                else if (files.Length == 1)
                {
                    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(files[0]);
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(files[0]);
                    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
                }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

js code:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/controllerforexample/Download',
                data: { data: data }// the first date is the variable in the action and the second data is a text.
            });
```

But nothing happens.

Someone maybe know what can be the problem?

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: What do you mean _nothing happens_. Have you debugged your code. Is the method being executed? Are you entering the `if (Directory.Exists(pathFolder))` block?

Comment: Is the method being executed? yes.
Are you entering the if (Directory.Exists(pathFolder)) block? yes
in the chrome debugger i see the content in the respons

Comment: You cannot use ajax to download a file.

Comment: Refer [Download Excel file via AJAX MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670209/download-excel-file-via-ajax-mvc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks. I change the ajax request to windows.location and it's work!!

Comment: That is a bit pointless (its just making a completely unnecessary call) - just use a `<a>` to redirect to that method (or use `location.href` directly)

Comment: before the download action i do another ajax call.. so i must doing like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a FileResult not an ActionResult

Comment: OP is already doing that - that is what `return File(...);` is