# Excel Export Not Working in MVC. No Errors being thrown

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc, export

I am trying to export all the users in my database to an excel file.

After running this code and debugging i run into no errors and the LetsExcelAll() method is being hit and run all the way through. Not sure what I am missing. When code is done running no errors are encountered and no download begins.

Controller:

```
public void LetsExcelAll()
    {
        try
        {
            var userRepo = new UsersRepository();
            XLWorkbook wb = null;

            wb = userRepo.DownloadUsers();

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Users.xlsx");

            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

REPO:

```
public XLWorkbook DownloadUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            if (thisConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                thisConnection.Open();

            MySqlCommand download = thisConnection.CreateCommand();

            download.CommandText = UserQueries.DownloadUsers;


            using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                sda.SelectCommand = download;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                    {
                        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "ALL_Users");
                        ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
                        ws.Columns().Style.Alignment.SetWrapText();

                        return wb;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            thisConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

VIEW: (HOW I CALL THE METHOD)

```
    $("#downloadAllUsers").click(function () {
    $.post("/Users/LetsExcelAll")                    
});
```

Comment: How `LetsExcelAll` called inside controller/code-behind? If it's called in MVC controller, you should return `FileStreamResult` instead of setting `Response` headers manually.

Comment: it is called through the view in jquery

Comment: How you're calling the method from view? Still unclear what view engine you're using and why `void` used as method return type instead of `ActionResult` or `FileResult`.

Comment: Added code from view how method is called

Comment: Is that `downloadAllUsers` a button element? The issue seems going clear: you're initiating AJAX request to invoke `void` method, that's why it not download anything. To download file you need to initiate GET request (not from AJAX) which returns `FileResult` with file name as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a file as response of [`jQuery.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method directly. It is necessary to store the file as byte array in `TempData` or `Session` state and pass it to another controller which marked as `HttpGetAttribute` to let user download the file.

Here are these steps to do:

1) Change `LetsExcelAll` method to return `JsonResult` containing file name and store output of `MemoryStream` inside `TempData`/`Session` variable with certain key as given below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LetsExcelAll()
{
    try
    {
        var userRepo = new UsersRepository();
        XLWorkbook wb = null;

        wb = userRepo.DownloadUsers();

        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);

            // set stream to starting position
            MyMemoryStream.Position = 0;

            // store file contents inside TempData
            TempData["ExcelFile"] = MyMemoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        // return file name as JSON data
        return new JsonResult() { Data = new { FileName = "Users.xlsx", Status = "Success" } };
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Status = "Nothing" } };
}
```

2) Set `window.location` in AJAX `POST` response to pass file name as query string parameter for action method name which uses `GET` (assumed `downloadAllUsers` is a button element).

```
$("#downloadAllUsers").click(function () {
    $.post("/Users/LetsExcelAll", function(data) {
        if (data.Status == "Success") {
            window.location = '/Users/DownloadFile?fileName=' + data.FileName;
        }
    });
});
```

3) Create a new controller with `HttpGetAttribute` using file name as input parameter and return `FileResult` from it.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
{
    if (TempData["ExcelFile"] != null)
    {
        var data = TempData["ExcelFile"] as byte[];
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        return File(data, contentType, fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        // if TempData messing up, return nothing
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

From this point, file downloading should working fine as expected.

Related issue:

[Download Excel file via AJAX MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670209/download-excel-file-via-ajax-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but with that code i am now getting a jquery error...

Comment: VM33:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (AllUsers:2502)

Comment: (This is the line causing the error) var response = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: `Unexpected token o` means that the response is already an object. No need to use `JSON.parse`, just use `data.Status` to reveal response state.